# Lock screen image goes to a default image after reboot

Tags: windows-10, images, lock-screen

I have selected a custom lock screen image for my windows 10 machine. The image shows correctly if I press the lock button while logged in, but if I reboot the machine, the image shown on the lock screen is not my custom one.

I have googled well and come up empty, even after trying registry editing.

**UPDATE 1**

Windows Version 1803 Build 17134.407

I am not on a domain and there are no policies in effect. It is a relatively new installation as well.

Comment: Have you selected the "Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen" option from the Lock screen menu?

Comment: Yes, that option is checked.

Comment: Please post the output of the start->run->WINVER command so we can know which version of Windows you are running.  Also, are you on a domain with any group policies running?